# TableView animation on selection

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview

I got this code - I want to animate change in width of a UIView of custom table view cell - here is what I implemented in the CustomTableViewCell class:

```
var expanded: Bool = false    
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    if !expanded {
        horizontalProgressView.hidden = true
    } else {
        horizontalProgressView.hidden = false
        horizontalProgressView.frame.size.width = 100.0
    }
}
```

Then in my viewController which has tableView and a delegate/datasource implemented I try:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.expanded = true
}
```

When I select the cell the the horizontalProgressView is visible (so the .hidden part is working) but the width is still the same I set in my storyboard. What am I missing?

Comment: what width do you have in a storyboard ? Also why not use auto layout ?

Comment: I have 5.0 width in the storyboard. No constraints.

Comment: `horizontalProgressView.layoutIfNeeded()` after `cell.expanded = true`?

Comment: I've tried it - doesn't work. I gave up on that method and used UIView.animateWithDuration directly in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Works fine. I was just wondering how to implement it in different way. Thanks!